# Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory for my Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token

I need to create lifetime token for my `WEB` Api. I’ve used the following [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-create-a-policy-for-a-native-app-that-calls-a-web-api) but the Policy doesn’t work.
As I’ve noticed, for my Web Api the following OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario works. 
I made it work by only using `AzureADPolicy` with setting -`IsOrganizationDefault` `$true` not `$false`.

My configuration:

```
OdataType             :
AlternativeIdentifier :
Definition            : {{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1, "AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00"}}}
DisplayName           : OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario
IsOrganizationDefault : True
KeyCredentials        : {}
Type                  : TokenLifetimePolicy

OdataType             :
AlternativeIdentifier :
Definition            : {{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1, "AccessTokenLifetime":"08:00:00", "MaxInactiveTime":"30.00:00:00", "MaxAgeMultiFactor":"until-revoked", "MaxAgeSingleFactor":"180.00:00:00"}}}
DisplayName           : WebApiDefaultPolicy
IsOrganizationDefault : False
KeyCredentials        : {}
Type                  : TokenLifetimePolicy

PS C:\Users\1> Get-Azureadapplicationpolicy -id 



Id                    : 
OdataType             : #microsoft.graph.policy
AlternativeIdentifier :
Definition            : {{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1, "AccessTokenLifetime":"08:00:00", "MaxInactiveTime":"30.00:00:00", "MaxAgeMultiFactor":"until-revoked", "MaxAgeSingleFactor":"180.00:00:00"}}}
DisplayName           : WebApiDefaultPolicy
IsOrganizationDefault : False
KeyCredentials        : {}
Type                  : TokenLifetimePolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Azureadapplicationpolicy` means that get the policy assigned to an application.
And as the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) said, `‑IsOrganizationDefault`, if true, sets the policy as the organization's default policy. If false, does nothing.

So the WebApiDefaultPolicy is assigned to application.

The policy for web sign-in is as below:

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Comment: I know it, thx. But this doesn`t work  ''I’ve used the following guide but the Policy doesn’t work....for my Web Api the following OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario works''

Comment: It's very odd. And I will confirm with other engineers.